# Ruby strptime not working while reading file

Tags: ruby, file, byte-order-mark, endianness

I have the following code:

```
require 'date'

f = File.open(filepath)

f.each_with_index do |line, i|
    a, b = line.split("\t")
    d = DateTime.strptime(a, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')
    puts "#{a} --- #{b}"
    break unless i < 100
end
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
c_reader.rb:10:in `strptime': invalid date (ArgumentError)
  from c_reader.rb:10:in `block in <main>'
  from c_reader.rb:6:in `each'
  from c_reader.rb:6:in `each_with_index'
  from c_reader.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

The file content:

```
1/30/2014 1:00 AM   1251.6  
1/30/2014 2:00 AM   1248  
1/30/2014 3:00 AM   1246.32  
1/30/2014 4:00 AM   1242.96  
1/30/2014 5:00 AM   1282.08  
1/30/2014 6:00 AM   1293.84  
1/30/2014 7:00 AM   1307.04  
1/30/2014 8:00 AM   1337.76  
1/30/2014 9:00 AM   1357.92
```

If I type this into IRB, it works perfect:

```
DateTime.strptime("1/30/2014 2:00 PM", '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')
```

can someone please tell me what's going on here?

Comment: double check your `split`

Comment: The split is working fine, I tested the code by removing the `DateTime` line.

Comment: We can't find any tabs in your input file, and have to assume they are after the "AM"|"PM" indicator.

Comment: Yes, they are... I didn't put it on the sample, just wanted to show the content, but you are right, the tabs are after the AM|PM

Comment: You need to provide working data to a question. Don't deliberately change the input in a way that makes your code sample fail. We expect a working sample of input and code that demonstrates/duplicates the problem you're seeing. As is, even if I replace the spaces in question with tabs I can't duplicate the problem.

Comment: My bad. Here's the sample file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0on4knx6ikt8pxr/test.csv

Comment: No, don't provide a link. Put a reduced sample of the data, the minimum necessary to duplicate the problem, in your question. Links rot, and without data in your question it will make no sense to people looking for the same question and answer. That said, is your file "CSV" ("comma-separated") or "TSV" ("tab-separated")?

Comment: The file is a TSV, but when I download it from the server it have the csv extension.

Comment: If I copy/paste the sample data the tabs gets removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example data wasn't matching what your code was trying to process so I adjusted that for this. Plus, it needed something to show the AM/PM was being honored.

With those tweaks to the data, your code works fine. `strptime` is returning valid DateTime objects.

```
require 'date'

[
  "1/30/2014 1:00 AM\t1251.6",
  "1/30/2014 2:00 AM\t1248",
  "1/30/2014 3:00 PM\t1246.32",
  "1/30/2014 4:00 PM\t1242.96",
].each do |line|
  a, b = line.split("\t")
  puts DateTime.strptime(a, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')
end
# >> 2014-01-30T01:00:00+00:00
# >> 2014-01-30T02:00:00+00:00
# >> 2014-01-30T15:00:00+00:00
# >> 2014-01-30T16:00:00+00:00
```

---

Your data file has a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) ("byte-order-mark"). The first two bytes indicate the ["endianness"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_endian#Little-endian) of the order of bytes in the file. In addition, each character actually occupies two bytes. This is a UTF-16LE file because `fffe` has a missing bit (`0xfe` == `0b11111110`) signifying the end of the byte-pair is smaller than the first byte. If it was `feff` it'd be a "big-endian":

```
0000000: fffe 3100 2f00 3300 3000 2f00 3200 3000  ..1./.3.0./.2.0.
```

Ruby doesn't know what to do with those because it's expecting its default of UTF-8. To fix that you need to tell Ruby how to interpret that. Look at the documentation for [`IO.new`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-c-new) to see how to define encodings. Ruby assumes data will be UTF-8, so the incoming data has to be converted from UTF-16LE to UTF-8. This is one way to do it:

```
require 'date'

File.open(
  "test.csv",
  "rb:BOM|UTF-16LE:UTF-8"
) do |fi|
  fi.each_with_index do |line, i|
    a, b = line.split("\t")
    d = DateTime.strptime(a, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')
    puts "#{ 1 + i } #{a} --- #{b}"
    break unless i < 100
  end
end
```

Running that outputs:

```
1 1/30/2014 1:00 AM --- 1251.6
2 1/30/2014 2:00 AM --- 1248
3 1/30/2014 3:00 AM --- 1246.32
4 1/30/2014 4:00 AM --- 1242.96
5 1/30/2014 5:00 AM --- 1282.08
6 1/30/2014 6:00 AM --- 1293.84
7 1/30/2014 7:00 AM --- 1307.04
8 1/30/2014 8:00 AM --- 1337.76
9 1/30/2014 9:00 AM --- 1357.92
```

Comment: I tried this code and it works, but I need it to work reading the file.  I put the link to the sample file I'm using, here's again: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0on4knx6ikt8pxr/test.csv

Comment: Not really. I just ran into these particular walls years ago.